# POA clique Ether

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I have created 3 nodes using Clique Proof of Authority (2 sealers). I know i can allocate ether in the genesis.json file while initializing it.

Question : Can the 3 nodes mine an ether or just the sealers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only sealer can mine/seal the block. Third node will only sync with the network.